# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java

Alguien sabe como solucionar la excepción java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError? Tengo entendido que se da cuando no encuentra la clase en el classpath, o me equivoco? Lo raro es que lo encontraba sin problema y de un dia para el otro dejo de hacerlo. Las clases que no encuentra es de un proyecto llamado **Trdiario**, el cual genero el jar y lo coloco en esta dirección: **C:\Empresa\lib**, junto con otras librerías auxiliares. Agrego a un proyecto llamado Desarrollo, una nueva librería, agregando todos los jars de la carpeta **C:\Empresa\lib** con **add Library** y como IDE utilizo Eclipse. 
Cabe destacar que solamente las clases del jar Trdiario.jar no me reconoce.
Agradecería si alguien puede orientarme a solucionar el conflicto.
Esta es la traza del error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: TotClt
    at com.TrDiario.TotCltC.ejecutarTotClt(TotCltW.cbl:400)
    at com.Riesgo.VerCategoriaJNDI.CargarDatos(VerCategoriaJNDI.java:559)
    at com.Riesgo.VerCategoriaJNDI$3.actionPerformed(VerCategoriaJNDI.java:143)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: TotClt
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 39 more
```

Al generar el jar del proyecto Trdiario me aparece este warning:

```
JAR export finished with warnings. See details for additional information.
  Could not find source file attribute for: 'C:\Users\User\desarrolloCD\Trdiario99\bin\com\TrDiario\PorSucursalC2$_MF_LCTYPE_1.class'
  Source name not found in a class file - exported all class files in Trdiario99/bin/com/TrDiario
```

Comment: En esos casos ayuda a veces hacer un `clean`y un `rebuild` desde el menú `Projects` de Eclipse. Y como se ha dicho en algunas respuestas, asegúrate de que tienes incluidas todas tus librerías. Maven parece complicado de usar al principio, pero no lo es tanto y te facilita la vida a la hora de agregar las librerías a tu proyecto. Saludos.

Comment: Si, ya hice el build y el clean pero sigue en lo mismo

Comment: Gracias por el aguante, solucioné el problema cambiando de Workspace. La verdad no sé que pasó pero ya funciona normalmente

Comment: Si alguna de las respuestas te ha dado la solución márcala como tal, si no, también podrías borrar la pregunta ya que es un problema difícil de reproducir. Lo digo para que no vayan quedando preguntas abiertas sin contestar. Saludos.

Comment: Lastimosamente ninguna respuesta solucionó mi problema en particular. Borraré la pregunta

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NoClassDefFoundError` se lanza cuando la máquina virtual intenta cargar una clase para ejecutar un método o crear una instancia y no encuentra la clase en cuestión. Esta clase sí estaba presente al compilar. Es decir, es un error de `runtime`.

Examina la traza de error, que indicará una clase concreta, y revisa que las librerías relacionadas están presentes en tiempo de ejecución.
Hay alguna librería con la que compilas tu proyecto `Informes` que también tendrás que copiar a `C:\Empresa\lib.`

Comment: Exactamente, es justamente lo que tengo. C:\Empresa\lib\Informes.jar, al igual que los demás jars: C:\Empresa\lib\*.jar. Coloco la traza en la respuesta

Comment: ¿En qué jar tienes la clase TotClt?

Comment: En Trdiario, hubo un error de nombres, el jar que me da problemas es Trdiario.jar

Comment: Comprueba que el proyecto que estás ejecutando tiene esa librería añadida al ejecutarse.

Comment: Tengo entendido que sí, ya que agrego la carpeta lib completa como librería. Y al compilar reconoce las clases. Como podría comprobar si se carga en tiempo de ejecución?

Comment: @Carlos una forma de evitar estos issues es usar un build manager como maven o gradle, facilitan muchísimo el control de dependencias de librerías y sus versiones.

Comment: Genial, voy a investigar sobre maven. Viene a ser como un framework?

Comment: A la pregunta agregué un warning que me aparece al generar el jar del proyecto Trdiario, ahora me percate de eso,

Comment: Gracias por el aguante, solucioné el problema cambiando de Workspace. La verdad no sé que pasó pero ya funciona normalmente

Answer (score 0):

Podria ser tambien por las versiones del compilador del .class que no reconoce.

Si el .class es mas avanzado (p.e. 1.8) que el JRE que la va a ejecutar (p.e. 1.7) entonces no la carga.

¿Te aparece por algun lado de la excepción esto: "major version" o "minor version"?

Comment: No por ningún lado. Lo raro es que hasta ayer funcionaba sin problema. Y hoy por arte de magia dejó de reconocer las clases de ese proyecto. Tengo varios proyectos metidos como jar, los cuales utiliza el Proyecto central digamos, pero solo las clases de ese proyecto en particular me esta generando problemas.

Answer (score 0):

Revisa que este [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]correctamente el lenguaje