# Cómo soluciono el error "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFDocument"

Tags: java, netbeans, apache-poi

Estoy tratando de generar un documento Word con java desde Netbeans utilizando la librería Apache Poi pero no lo consigo. He intentando actualizar los ficheros (Poi 5.0.0) y nada. Les paso foto del pequeño pedazo de código que escribí a modo de prueba y del error generado. Alguna sugerencia?[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, bienvenido, te invito a leer cómo preguntar https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. El código se debe colocar en texto.

Comment: Esta pregunta pude ser duplicado de https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/60313/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror.

Comment: Bienvenido! Te recomiendo que evites capturas de pantalla tanto para código como para errores, es mucho mas facil ayudar si lo copias y lo pegas. Te recomiendo realices el [Recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) de la comunidad así te familiarizas y de paso ganas tu primer medalla